# unexpected behavior of bitwise shifting using gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, bit-shift

I have a test program like this:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned n = 32;

    printf("ans << 32 = 0x%X\n", (~0x0U) << 32);
    printf("ans >> 32 = 0x%X\n", (~0x0U) >> 32);

    printf("ans << n(32) = 0x%X\n", (~0x0U) << n);
    printf("ans >> n(32) = 0x%X\n", (~0x0U) >> n);

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
ans << 32 = 0x0  ... (1)  
ans >> 32 = 0x0  ... (2)  
ans << n(32) = 0xFFFFFFFF  ... (3)  
ans >> n(32) = 0xFFFFFFFF  ... (4)
```

I was expecting (1) and (3) to be the same, as well as (2) and (4) to be the same.

Using gcc version: gcc.real (Ubuntu 4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1

What is happening?

Comment: FWIW: http://ideone.com/RqWE9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shifting by the size of the type is undefined behavior, according to the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), § 6.5.7.3:

> **6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**
>   (...) If the value of
>   the right operand is negative or is greater than **or equal** to the width
>   of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Your compiler should warn you about this:

```
$ gcc shift.c -o shift -Wall
shift.c: In function ‘main’:
shift.c:5:5: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
shift.c:6:5: warning: right shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
```

If you look at the [assembler code](http://pastebin.com/RGTxDxee) gcc is generating, you'll see it is actually calculating the first two results at compilation time.  Simplified:

```
main:
    movl    $0, %esi
    call    printf

    movl    $0, %esi
    call    printf

    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx  ; -4(%rbp) is n
    movl    $-1, %esi
    sall    %cl, %esi       ; This ignores all but the 5 lowest bits of %cl/%ecx
    call    printf

    movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
    movl    $-1, %esi
    shrl    %cl, %esi
    call    printf
```

Comment: I am not shifting by MORE than the size of type... I am shifting equal to the size of the type

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes Oops, I meant greater than *or equal*. Updated, and quoted the standard.

Comment: Better now +1. @puffadder I hope this teaches you to enable and not ignore your compiler warnings ;)

Comment: but 32 bits is equal to the size of the type. The C standard says "greater than or equal"

Comment: Read the quoted spec again.  It says "greater than or equal".  A 32 bit shift on a 32 bit operand is undefined according to the spec.  It is common for processors to ignore all but the low 5 bits of the shift amount, which causes `x << 32 == x` on those processors, including x86.  On other processors zeroes will be shifted in.  The C standard was flexible to allow implementations to do the fast thing on all processors.

Comment: @Dietrich thanks for explaining the unusual result (UB explains why you can't expect 0, but doesn't explain why GCC decided to produce a zigamorph).

Comment: @puffadder Added an explanation to why this specific behavior is observed (The assembler code is heavily simplified, since the original looks pretty ugly without optimization). Also, this is on x64, with a calling convention that uses the `ESI` register for the second function parameter. Your mileage may vary depending on compiler version, optimization flags, and architecture.