# Is it a bug in g++?

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

uint32_t k[] = {0, 1, 17};

template <typename T>
bool f(T *data, int i) {
    return data[0] < (T)(1 << k[i]);
}

int main() {
    uint8_t v = 0;
    cout << f(&v, 2) << endl;
    cout << (0 < (uint8_t)(1 << 17)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
g++ a.cpp && ./a.out
1
0
```

Why am I getting these results?

Comment: @HassanTM 1 and 0, I gather.

Comment: What did you expect to output?

Comment: What result did you expect and what result did you get?

Comment: It's not a bug in g++, it's just you don't know what this should do.

Comment: `0<0` would always return `0`

Comment: Hmmm... http://codepad.org/ESPOc0Zj

Comment: question is valid..why those downvotes

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: Because it shows lack of effort on the asker's part.  At the very least, he could have(should have) stated the results he expects, and why he expects those results.

Comment: GCC 4.7 does print 1,0. Clang 3.2 prints 0,0 as expected.

Comment: And another hmmm... http://ideone.com/UPH9gz

Comment: Interesting: http://ideone.com/N41MOx

Comment: what should, in your opinion, be the result of expression `(uint8_t)(1 << 17)`?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic if `1 << 17` does not cause UB and `uint8_t` is what it says it is, it should be 0.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze .. which is what i get with apples llvm 4.1 (clang). 0 0.

Comment: @PaulR: I don't understand how codepad gives that result. I tried it with the same GCC version and same compiler options they claim to use and it gives 1,0. In addition, it's really strange that it outputs `false` instead of `0` when `boolalpha` hasn't been specified.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214263/unexpected-behavior-of-bitwise-shifting-using-gcc

Comment: @Stefan: That's not the issue here, the shift here is only by 17 so is not undefined (when `int` is 32 bits).

Comment: @interjay right, sry. i thought (T) was applied to the 1, but it is applied to the result of the only.

Comment: it is strange that return 0 < 0 means return true..

Comment: What is so interesting in this "question" that it gets up voted to the sky? -1

Comment: @SChepurin do you know why? I just feel very strange.

Comment: @SChepurin: the question is interesting because compiler bugs are interesting. Unless you understand the bug (and please explain it then), it is not possible to know what constructs gcc misinterprets.

Comment: Someone filed a PR here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56051

Comment: You forgot to explain what different behaviour you were expecting.

Answer (score 20):

It looks like gcc reverses the shift and applies it to the other side, and I guess this is a bug.

In C (instead of C++) the same thing happens, and C translated to asm is easier to read, so I'm using C here; also I reduced the test cases (dropping templates and the k array).
foo() is the original buggy f() function, foo1() is what foo() behaves like with gcc but shouldn't, and bar() shows what foo() should look like apart from the pointer read.

I'm on 64-bit, but 32-bit is the same apart from the parameter handling and finding k.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t k = 17;
char foo(uint8_t *data) {
    return *data < (uint8_t)(1<<k);
/*
with gcc -O3 -S: (gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5))
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    movl    k(%rip), %ecx
    shrb    %cl, %al
    testb   %al, %al
    sete    %al
    ret
*/
}
char foo1(uint8_t *data) {
    return (((uint32_t)*data) >> k) < 1;
/*
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    movl    k(%rip), %ecx
    shrl    %cl, %eax
    testl   %eax, %eax
    sete    %al
    ret
*/
}
char bar(uint8_t data) {
    return data < (uint8_t)(1<<k);
/*
    movl    k(%rip), %ecx
    movl    $1, %eax
    sall    %cl, %eax
    cmpb    %al, %dil
    setb    %al
    ret
*/
}

int main() {
    uint8_t v = 0;
    printf("All should be 0: %i %i %i\n", foo(&v), foo1(&v), bar(v));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Finally* a case where the adage “premature optimisation is the root of all evil” *really* applies!

Comment: If you want something easier to read than asm, try the -fdump-tree-all option in gcc.

Answer (score 8):

If your `int` is 16-bit long, you're running into undefined behavior and either result is "OK".

Shifting N-bit integers by N or more bit positions left or right results in undefined behavior.

Since this happens with 32-bit ints, this is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: This happens with GCC on a platform with 32-bit ints though.

Comment: @interjay Then, unless I'm missing something, it looks like a bug.

Comment: I think there is a bug in gcc and that this post doesn't answer the OP.

Answer (score 4):

**Here are some more data points:**

basically, it looks like gcc optimizes (even in when the -O flag is off and -g is on):

```
    [variable] < (type-cast)(1 << [variable2])
```

to

```
    ((type-cast)[variable] >> [variable2]) == 0
```

and

```
    [variable] >= (type-cast)(1 << [variable2])
```

to

```
    ((type-cast)[variable] >> [variable2]) != 0
```

where [variable] needs to be an array access.

I guess the advantage here is that it doesn't have to load the literal 1 into a register, which saves 1 register.

So here are the data points:

- changing 1 to a number > 1 forces it to implement the correct version.
- changing any of the variables to a literal forces it to implement the correct version
- changing [variable] to a non array access forces it to implement the correct version
- [variable] > (type-cast)(1 << [variable2]) implements the correct version.

I suspect this is all trying to save a register.  When [variable] is an array access, it needs to also keep an index.  Someone probably thought this is so clever, until it's wrong.

Using code from the bug report http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56051

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int a, s = 8;
        unsigned char data[1] = {0};

        a = data[0] < (unsigned char) (1 << s);
        printf("%d\n", a);

        return 0;
    }
```

compiled with gcc -O2 -S

```
     .globl main
            .type   main, @function
    main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $8, %esp
    pushl   $1                ***** seems it already precomputed the result to be 1
    pushl   $.LC0
    pushl   $1
    call    __printf_chk
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    -4(%ebp), %ecx
    leave
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
```

compile with just gcc -S

```
    .globl main
            .type   main, @function
    main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $8, -12(%ebp)
    movb    $0, -17(%ebp)
    movb    -17(%ebp), %dl
    movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
    movb    %dl, %bl
    movb    %al, %cl
    shrb    %cl, %bl                      ****** (unsigned char)data[0] >> s => %bl
    movb    %bl, %al                              %bl => %al
    testb   %al, %al                              %al = 0?
    sete    %dl
    movl    $0, %eax
    movb    %dl, %al
    movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
    movl    $.LC0, %eax
    subl    $8, %esp
    pushl   -16(%ebp)
    pushl   %eax
    call    printf
    addl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, %eax
    leal    -8(%ebp), %esp
    addl    $0, %esp
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
```

I guess the next step is to dig through gcc's source code.

Comment: In case you missed it, the PR gives you the exact line in gcc source code where this optimization happens... It happens for < and >= if the lhs is unsigned and the rhs is (a cast of) 1 << var. Because of the time at which the optimization occurs, it happens only if the syntax tree is exactly this (no going through variables or whatever).

Comment: @MarcGlisse, It is so specific that I can't help but wonder if someone wise ass thought this is a clever optimization to save a register when it is needed most.  Otherwise, why would it not happen for non-array access?  what's PR?  I am looking in the bug report, but not seeing it.  I tried replacing data[0] with a local variable d, and that actually made it work.  Also tried changing variables to literals, and that works, too.

Comment: It does happen for non-arrays, and please refrain from such rude comments.

Comment: this piece of code works correctly (d doesn't get optimized out):    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int a, s =8;
        int d = 0;
        a = d < (unsigned char)(1 << s);
        printf("%d\n", a);

        return 0;
    }

Comment: also changing int d = 0; to unsigned char d = 0; also works.

Comment: ah i see the source code line.  overlooked it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure we're talking undefined behaviour here - converting a "large" integer to a smaller, of a value that doesn't fit in the size of the new value, is undefined as far as I know. 131072 definitely doesn't fit in a uint_8.

Although looking at the code generated, I'd say that it's probably not quite right, since it does "sete" rather than "setb"??? That does seem very suspicios to me.

If I turn the expression around:

```
return (T)(1<<k[i])  >  data[0];
```

then it uses a "seta" instruction, which is what I'd expect. I'll do a bit more digging - but something seems a bit wrong.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752567/casting-a-large-number-type-to-a-smaller-type casting to an unsigned smaller type is well defined. (and should do what we expect)

Comment: I notice your code says "sete" as well. I haven't delved very deeply into it, but it doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: The generated code is the equivalent of `test eax, eax; setz al`, which looks like a reasonable way of returning `x == 0`, which for `unsigned int` is identical to `x < 1`. Seems okay to me.

Comment: Yes, but x < 1 is not the same as x < (1 << k) - and I looked at the UNOPTIMIZED code, so it would not do any constant replacement. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: x < (1 << k) is "the same" as (x >> k) < 1

Comment: I'm not sure what code transformations GCC does at which optimization settings, but it seems like it just changed `x < (1 << k)` to `(x >> k) < 1` and missed the truncating `(T)` cast. Interestingly, extracting `1 << k` to a temporary variable fixed the problem for me (MinGW GCC 4.6.2).

Comment: Gcc sometimes optimizes things during parsing (even at -O0). It shouldn't, but that's legacy and there will be a lot of work moving all those optimizations to a later stage.